# Why isn't this python code for percentage calculation not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

An exam is conducted for 470 marks . What is the percentage if i secure 450 marks
Note that 100/470 = 0.21276595744

```
def percent(total):
percent = total*0.21276595744
x= percent(int(450))
print (percent(450))
```

Output :
None

Comment: What are you expecting when you define a method and a variable with the same name?

Comment: def percentage(total):
    percentage = total*0.21276595744
x= percentage(int(450))
print (x)
I've tried this doesn't work either. Sorry Noob here

Comment: Your function should return value

Comment: U need to work on basics first ...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to return a value in your function:

```
def percent(total):
    return total*0.21276595744

print (percent(450))
```